# Node pg-promise, bind multiple values with type casting

Tags: pg-promise

I'm currently using the [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) library to insert multiple values into a database in the format:

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['booking_id', {name:'timeslot', cast:'timestamp'}], {table: 'booking'});

// data input values:
const values = [];
bookings.forEach(slot => {
   values.push({booking_id: booking_id, timeslot: slot});
});
```

Where I need timeslot to be a timestamp. However it comes into the API as value like

`1515586500.0`

Using the above `cast` property my query gets resolved like so

```
insert into "booking"("booking_id","timeslot") values(1,'1515586500.0'::timestamp)
```

however this throws an error of `cannot cast type numeric to timestamp without time zone`

If I use the `to_timestamp` function however this works how I need it to e.g

```
insert into "booking"("booking_id","timeslot") values(1,to_timestamp('1515586500.0'));
```

Is there any way I can get pg-promise to use `to_timestamp` rather than the `::timestamp` notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the column definition to this one:

```js
{
    name: 'timeslot',
    mod: ':raw',
    init: c => pgp.as.format('to_timestamp($1)', c.value)
}
```

or

```js
{
    name: 'timeslot',
    mod: ':raw',
    init: c => pgp.as.format('to_timestamp(${value})', c)
}
```

...as per the [Column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html) type documentation.

Or you can use [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting) on the type, to self-format automatically.

---

Also, you do not need to remap values to suit the `ColumnSet` object, you use `ColumnSet` object to fit the data instead. So if the value for column `timeslot` is in property `slot`, you just use `prop: 'slot'` within your column definition to change where the value is coming from.