# Parse geometry object to wkt by node.js

Tags: node.js, postgis, postgresql-10, wkt

This is my postgresql table:

```
create table scheduled_locations
(
  id           uuid     not null,
  device_id    text     not null,
  user_id      uuid,
  created_date date,
  st_astext    geometry not null
    constraint scheduled_locations_idkey
    primary key
);

alter table scheduled_locations
  owner to postgres;

create index gist_idx
  on scheduled_locations (st_astext);
```

By nodejs i want to fill my table. this is my json object that i want to store into my this table:

```
const dataSingle = {
    'id': uuidv1(),
    'device_id': user.device_id,
    'user_id': user.user_id,
    'created_date': user.date,
    'st_astext': user.multiLine
};
```

user.multiLine has this value:

```
user.multiLine
Object {type: "Feature", properties: Object, geometry: Object}
geometry:Object {type: "MultiLineString", coordinates: Array(23)}
properties:Object {}
type:"Feature"
__proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}
```

By using pg-promise i want to save into postgresql:

```
await db.any(pgp.helpers.insert(dataSingle, null, 'scheduled_locations'));
```

But i got this error :

```
Error: parse error - invalid geometry
code:"XX000"
column:undefined
constraint:undefined
dataType:undefined
detail:undefined
file:"lwgeom_pg.c"
hint:""{"" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry"
internalPosition:undefined
internalQuery:undefined
length:151
line:"92"
message:"parse error - invalid geometry"
name:"error"
position:"230"
routine:"pg_parser_errhint"
schema:undefined
severity:"ERROR"
stack:"error: parse error - invalid geometry\n    at Connection.parseE (e:\Projects\NodeJs\HistoricalLogPg\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:553:11)\n    at Connection.parseMessage (e:\Projects\NodeJs\HistoricalLogPg\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:378:19)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (e:\Projects\NodeJs\HistoricalLogPg\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:119:22)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)\n    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)\n    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)\n    at TCP.onread (net.js:639:20)"
table:undefined
where:undefined
```

I am new in gis stuff but why i got this error ? `user.multiLine` is `MultiLineString` and my table has a geometry column..

Even i have used pg-promise column but still have above error:

```
const getPoint = col => {
    const p = col.source;
    return p ? pgp.as.format('st_astext(${multiLine})', p) : 'NULL';
};

const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([

    {
        name: 'id',
        mod: ':raw',
        init: generate_id
    },
    'device_id',
    'user_id',
    {
        name: 'created_date',
        prop: 'date'
    },
    {
        name: 'st_astext',
        prop: 'multiLine',
        mod: ':raw',
        init: getPoint
    }
], {
    table: 'scheduled_locations'
});

let results = await db.any(pgp.helpers.insert(user, cs));
```

Comment: You should define a proper `ColumnSet` object, and define the special column to self-format properly. Here's the most recent question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589508/node-pg-promise-bind-multiple-values-with-type-casting

Comment: I do that but my problem is  because of `gis` stuff @vitaly-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is that you double-redirect into property `multiLine`, i.e. you first tell `ColumnSet` that the value is in `multiLine`, and then you re-do that inside the formatting logic.

Replace the column with this:

```
{
    name: 'st_astext',
    mod: ':raw',
    init: getPoint
}
```

And then I'm guessing you want to check if the value is set, and not if the whole object is set. So the correct implementation for `getPoint` should be:

```
const getPoint = col => {
    const p = col.source.multiLine;
    return p ? pgp.as.format('st_astext($1)', p) : 'NULL';
};
```

P.S. I still see a problem with your code. You are returning `NULL` for the column when the value is not set, while in the table it is clearly defined as non-NULL: `st_astext geometry not null`. That's a contradiction you need to fix.

Comment: tanks dude i have changed geometry row to accept null but this error is that i got `message:"index row requires 458888 bytes, maximum size is 8191"` @vitaly-t

Comment: @sayreskabir That's an unrelated error, dude, you need to research separately.

Comment: Thanks bro @vitaly-t